# Define variable status by priority

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a situation here.
I want to define a search status based on some priorities.
this are the possible status: notGenerated, generated, processing, invalidInput

I have a array like this:
['notGenerated', 'generated', 'generated', 'processing', 'invalidInput']

the priority is, if some element on array has 'notGenerated' the search status is 'notGenerated'

for the search status be 'generated', the elements on array cant be 'processing' or 'notGenerated', and need to has 'generated' in some of them.

for the search status be 'processing', some element on array must be 'processing' and the elements on array cant be 'notGenerated'.

for the 'invalidInput', we need that every element on the array be 'invalidInput'.

I make this code but i think its very ugly, how can i improve it?

```
    resultsStatus = ['someStatus', 'someStatus', 'someStatus']

    let searchStatus;
    const hasNotGenerated = resultsStatus.includes('notGenerated');
    const hasProcessing = resultsStatus.includes('processing');
    const hasGenerated = resultsStatus.includes('generated');
    const allInvalidInput = resultsStatus.filter((result) => result.status === 'invalidInput');

    if (hasNotGenerated) searchStatus = 'notGenerated';
    if (hasGenerated && !hasProcessing) searchStatus = 'generated';
    if (resultsStatus.length === allInvalidInput.length) searchStatus = 'invalidInput';

    return searchStatus;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define "exit points" from your function, as soon as a criterion is satisfied.

Additionally, it's preferable to use an enum, as it guarantees no typos or other inconsistencies in your statuses.

```js
const Status = {
  NOT_GENERATED: 'notGenerated',
  GENERATED: 'generated',
  PROCESSING: 'processing',
  INVALID: 'invalidInput',
};

function determineStatus(arr) {
  if (arr.includes(Status.NOT_GENERATED)) return Status.NOT_GENERATED;

  // If the array included 'notGenerated', it'd be returned on the previous check
  if (arr.includes(Status.PROCESSING)) return Status.PROCESSING;

  // If the array included 'notGenerated' or 'processing', it'd be returned on the previous checks
  if (arr.includes(Status.GENERATED)) return Status.GENERATED;

  if (arr.every(element => element === Status.INVALID)) return Status.INVALID;
}
```